# Make the admin dashboard in the right way

Tags: reactjs, yii2, admin, react-redux, dashboard

I use Yii2, ReactJS and Redux in my project. So, client side is good and beautiful, but current admin panel is the most ugly thing in the world (legacy). My goal is create new one.

How can I make admin dashboard using my stack?

My needs:

- Modular structure
- Individual structure of the state of each module
- Write frontend fully on React and make it interactive (React Router?)
- Not only CRUD. Some sections may be only informative, with some buttons and checkboxes. Or reports. Or for other purposes. (dont think that REST is only one thing that I need)
- Don't wanna store all of DB records in the global redux state. But wanna load all records and other information by need (Depending on the page, sections, current state etc). And it should automatically clean off the state once I change page.
- Maybe there's something else that I don't know yet..)

I need advice from professionals. Maybe articles or good libraries that can help me. I'll be very grateful.

P.S.This question is all about how to connect backend and frontend and keep state clean. Not about UX or UI

P.P.S. Sorry for my "Russian" English. Hope you'll understand me :)

Comment: A bit late here, but have you tried https://adminjs.co/ It's pretty cool.